# px4 command doesn't open gazebo GUI robustly and with model as specified

Tags: gazebo, px4, gazebo-gui

In my setup I start the gazebo simulation  with my custom world.
In a second step I start up px4 with the args `./build/px4_sitl_default/bin/px4` command. In these args, I give it my custom world file (as I gave to gazebo) and my custom drone model and pose and so on. This pipeline works fine.

Now from what I understand from the [px4 documentation](https://docs.px4.io/main/en/sim_gazebo_gz/#gazebo-simulation), It should be possible to start the whole pipeline mentioned above (aka certain drone at certain pose in certain map) with simply the mentioned px4 command. When I do this the gz GUI opens but without the drone. Bash output:
[image]

When closing everything and running the command again it doesn't open gazebo anymore no matter how often I try again. QGC however seems to be connected to gazebo as I can execute the mission from start to end.

Any idea what might be the problem?

The commands used are :
(For the working pipeline with manual gz start first):

```
terminal1: source gazebo
terminal1: gz sim --verbose 3 $HOME/gazebo_ws/worlds/${WORLD}.sdf # with WORLD set correctly beforehand

terminal2: source gazebo
terminal2: gz service -s /world/map/control --reqtype gz.msgs.WorldControl --reptype gz.msgs.Boolean --timeout 3000 --req 'pause: 0'
terminal2: cd path/to/px4_autopilot
terminal2: PX4_SYS_AUTOSTART=4001 PX4_GZ_MODEL=uav_${UAV} PX4_GZ_MODEL_POSE='${POSE}' PX4_GZ_WORLD='${WORLD}' ./build/px4_sitl_default/bin/px4
terminal2: Setup without manual gz GUI call and the above mentioned problems: Just the terminal 2 commands
```

##### Notes

I played around both with the HEADLESS and other flags in the px4 command. not only did they not help to open the gazebo GUI, setting `HEADLESS=1` and not opening gz separately still opened gazebo when only using the px4 command.